# Advanced center align - possible with CSS?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I'm wondering if it's possible to center-align a paragraph, but somehow **not** to make all the lines spread as wide as the div. It could be for example shorter-longer-shorter-longer or so.

[image]

Fiddle (not the way I want it): http://jsfiddle.net/u3v6x9fb/

```
p {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: could you add an image of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Hi can please be more specific? May a image you can give us a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code.

Comment: It looks like you need to either use `white-space: pre` or hard code the line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can give a width to the `<p>` tag.
- You can also manually apply `<br />` linebreaks to where you want to go to the next line.
- And you can make 2 classes e.g. `.pshort & .plong`, and apply different width to both, and make a text with those 2 classes.

Comment: I was hoping to make it in a more elegant way, but if that's the way to do it, thank you, I'll accept your answer as soon as the option is active.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one simple way of adding the line breaks where you need them, use `white-space: pre-line` on the `p` element.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space

At least you don't need to explicitly add `<br>` tags or wrap each line in a `span` or `div`.

```css
p {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in augue malesuada, tempus odio a, dapibus odio. Vestibulum convallis imperdiet est, sed tincidunt nisi tempus id. Ut quis tempor erat. Vivamus maximus, lectus non auctor iaculis, 
ipsum erat sagittis diam, id rutrum justo elit vel neque.
Proin nulla libero, egestas sit amet lorem a, accumsan molestie velit. 
Aliquam sed enim quis est rutrum consectetur. Aliquam tincidunt, eros vitae pharetra consectetur, eros tellus aliquet diam, eu auctor orci lectus ut elit. 
Nunc eu dui nec ante dignissim pretium.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a class to the required paragraph and center it.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3v6x9fb/1/)

CSS

```
p {

    text-align: center;
}

p.narrow {
    width:60%;
    margin: auto;

}
```

Comment: This way I can only make whole paragraphs some narrow and I meant making every second line (or so) of a paragraph more narrow.

Comment: @oneday That's not possible...CSS cannot detect text content.